# Issue in NumberPicker tag in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using `android studio 1.2.1.1`, I don't why `number picker` cause an error like this. I searched a lot over the internet but couldn't find a suitable answer.

`NumberPicker` tag  underlined by a red skew line.But it doesn't make any compile time error.

```
<NumberPicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/attemptPicker"
    android:scaleX="1.5"
    android:scaleY="1.5"
    android:paddingTop="50.8mm"
    android:paddingLeft="6mm"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtrescue"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtrescue" />
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: can you hover your mouse on that red error line, what it is saying when you hover the mouse?

Comment: NumberPicker class is added in API level 11 and if your min api level is lower then 11 thrn it mighr

Comment: I tried to change the API level. But there wasn't API 11 even in the SDK. So i choosed API 19. Now the error is gone. But Still it doesn't show the number picker. But in component tree when i keep mouse pointer on the number picker it hoovers "When you define paddingLeft you should probably also define paddingRight for right-to-left symmetry". What should I do now?

Comment: means in your application it is not showing number picker?

Comment: put your complete XML file here?

Comment: It shows small number icon. It doesn't even look like a number picker. Just two horizontal lines and in between a little zero. I tried to change the size. But it didn't work

Comment: That is the default look of the number picker in android. If you want to customized it then you need to user third party or you need to extends and customize your number picker.

Comment: Can you please tell me where can i learn to customize it? I'm new to android so know idea what to do. Any website or tutorial i should prefer other than android developer site?

Comment: there is no official site for such, you can search on github.com for source.